# delete multiple documents at once mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am only to delete one record at a time in Mongodb cloud db (Atlas). I have 60 records to delete and it is painful. I do not see an obvious way to delete multiple records at once. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You actually can't bulk delete in MongoDB Atlas. [See MongoDB Atlas info on the filter section AKA Data Explorer](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/data-explorer/index.html). However you can run standard queries, like find, remove once you connect to the database using your Atlas credentials.

At the clusters view, click connect on the cluster with the collection you would like to query/modify. Then follow the UI to get your connection string using Mongo Shell. If you need a GUI way to delete, you may consider Mongo Compass. Atlas also provides instructions how to connect via Compass on the same page.

[image: Connect Menu]

Comment: I have Compass but there isn't a way to delete multiple items at once. I was hoping it would be as easy as phpMyAdmin where you can check the records you want to remove and just click "delete"

Comment: I think you are right that Compass doesn't allow for deleting multiple items at once. It seems you will have to use Mongo Shell to delete via query.

Comment: Why is this not a feature in atlas?  I can't think of any database platforms I know of that do not have a multiple delete option.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep any of the documents inside a collection you can **just drop the entire collection** through mongodb atlas app. `That will delete all the documents inside your collection`. Don't worry the collection will get created on its own when you create a document. I find this way more convenient than installing the mongodb shell and then running the remove query.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use mLab which is owned by MongoDB. There is an option in there for deleteing all documents.

[mLab.com](https://mlab.com/login/)

[image: mLab.com]

Comment: This answer isn't relevant anymore, as mLab is shutting down (and the question is tagged 'atlas' also).

Comment: mLab is not anymore seems to be the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS code, I think the easiest way is to install the MongoDB extension. From there you can easily execute queries against the database cluster.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robomongo which is like Compass but with delete feature so you could use a query like this: deleteMany({name: "dang"})
https://robomongo.org/

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$multi=true` in remove method of the collection in mongo shell

```
db.collectionName.remove({where condition}, {$multi:true})
```

Will delete all the records matching the conditions.

If you are using the JPA or mongo-data repository in any language then you might have below methods:

```
 deleteAllByColumnName(ColumnNameValue)
```

or

```
 deleteAll()
```

in the interface class, you just need to use the dao.deleteAll() method.

For more documents on **Repository Delete Queries**  please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.delete)

Comment: @where do I find that in Atlas? The only thing I see is a search type field that says FILTER with a FIND button next to it

Comment: the question is about Atlas not mongo shell